# Could not find or load main class Example

Tags: java

I am new to programming, java and stackoverflow. I am starting with Herbert Schidlt 9th edition and compiling first program Example. java . 
It gets compiled when I type path 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac" Example.java
But it do not gets compiled when I type
java Example.java
and gives error "could not find or load main class Example"

I tried changing Path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin or C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin or C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac that I learnt from various Stackoverflow discussions but it do not works.

Also compiler check do not works with javac -version but works well with java -version

Please help. I am stuck up with this problem from last 5 days and have tried many things from various discussions.

Comment: Please paste Example.java here.

Comment: Have you configured your path

Comment: `javac` compiles, `java` runs. "it do not gets compiled when I type java Example.java" you should type "javac Example.java" instead.

Answer (score -1):

To compile, use `javac Example.java`. `java Example` for running the compiled class. You are using `java Example.java`. You are confused when to use `java` and `javac`.

Please refer this - https://teamtreehouse.com/community/difference-between-java-and-javac

Also this - [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: You've noticed that OP wrote *"It gets compiled when I type path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac" Example.java"*, right? *"But it do not gets compiled when I type java Example.java"* Is obviously a misunderstand what "java" does.

Comment: I think the real problem is at first step when I type javac Example.java it shows 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command..... and the answer for all such discussions goes back to path which I mentioned earlier that I have set. but no luck till now. And I deleted the old path rather adding on it so now I don't know what old path was and have I screwed something badly. Sorry all I am new and I think a bit stupid

Comment: Did  you try restarting your command line after changing the environment variables.

Comment: yes i even restarted my pc but no luck

Comment: currently it is C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\

Comment: i dont know what restarting command line means. it always starts with C:\users\samsung> on which I add cd compsci and enter to go to my folder where program is kept

Comment: Add "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\" to your path now, open and close command line and type `javac -version` and check the output

Comment: guys I cracked it. I compiled with javaw Example.java then executed java Example and it worked. I learned somewhere in forum that javaw is used when we dont need command prompt or something like that but I used it in command prompt just to see my program running. Please help to understand why javac is not being recognized.

Comment: javaw is same as java except that it is windowed. Delete Example.class and  run the same command again. I don't think it works. javac is for compiling and javaw is for executing. One cannot replace the other.